# Wordpress get_post_meta issue

Tags: php, posts, functions, theme-development

I'm new to php and was assigned some code to fix within a Wordpress theme, but I cannot figure it out for anything. The code is for the home page of a custom theme and it is supposed to pull the most recent blog posts and put them in a 3x2 grid at the top of the page.

[Here's](http://test.j2webproduction.com/test/) the page in question

and here's the code from the index.php file (I believe that's where the problem lies)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $woo_options; ?>
<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_featured_disable'] <> "true" ) include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/featured.php'); ?>
<?php

$t = array();

$t[2] = "A";
$t[5] = "B";

query_posts('post_type=infobox&order=ASC&posts_per_page=20&meta_value=false');

if (have_posts()) :

        $a = array(0,1,3,4); $i = 0;

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $m = "";

        $m .= "<div class=\"bskhp_t\" style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px'>";
        $m .= "<a href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\"><img src=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini', $single = true)."\" alt=\"\" class=\"home-icon\"></a>";
        $m .= "<div class=\"bskhp_f\">";
        $m .= "<h3><a href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\">".get_the_title()."</a></h3>";
        $m .= "<p>".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_excerpt', true)."</p>";
        $m .= "<a style='font-family:arial;font-size:13px;text-transform: uppercase' href=\"".get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', $single = true)."\" class=\"btn\">";
        $m .= "<span>Read More</span></a>";
        $m .= "</div>";
        $m .= "</div>";



        $t[$a[$i++]] = $m;

        endwhile;

endif;

$t[2] = $t[0];
$t[3] = $t[0];
$t[4] = $t[0];
$t[5] = $t[0];
```

This code for some reason will not pull the latest blog posts and put them in the 3x2 grid, except for the first two items, and I have no idea why. I believe the problem is within the get_post_meta function, but my knowledge is too sparse to debug it.

Can anyone help? I would be very gracious :)

Comment: edited to cut down the code and highlight the affected area, code lacks a ?> because I cut it off in the middle of the file

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Convert that `query_posts` to a `new WP_QUERY` then `var_dump()` the query. Do you see the posts you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make some improvements to your template file. Try this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $woo_options; ?>
<?php if ( $woo_options['woo_featured_disable'] <> "true" ) include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/featured.php'); ?>
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'infobox',
    'order' => 'DESC', // DESC for newer first.
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page' => 6 // For a 3x2 grid.
);

$latest = new WP_Query( $args ); // You now have an object you can use in 'The Loop'.

if ( $latest->have_posts() ) {
    while ($latest->have_posts()) : $latest->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="bskhp_t">
            <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', true); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini', true); ?>" alt="" class="home-icon">
            </a>
            <div class="bskhp_f">
                <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', true); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_excerpt', true); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mini_readmore', true); ?>">
                    <span>Read more</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile;
}
```

I removed the CSS since you should move it into another file.

Then, for a 3x2 grid, I suggest you doing so using CSS. Try:

```
.bskhp_t {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}
```

It's ideal if the parent container of `.bskhp_t` DIVs takes all available width.

I didn't tested this code so let me know if you had some issues ;)

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! Unfortunately this code worked for a few minutes, but then "broke" and my old issue returned. I have no idea why that would be the case, as there's nothing that I know of overriding this file

Comment: If that worked it may still be the right answer ;) Maybe you broke something elsewhere, but I can't help you without more info !

Comment: I was wrong, Apparently I had created a home.php file and it was overriding, thank you again! You are a lifesaver!